# Debugging iOS Performance Remotely

Tags: objective-c, ios, remote-debugging, performance-testing

I have an iOS application that is exhibiting performance issues. The problem is that the developers can't reproduce it. And the user who can reproduce the problem is physically nowhere near the developers. This means we can't use Instruments to help debug the problem.

Is there anyway we can do method level timing?

Comment: You can get execution logs and go through it to debug your problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can say to the person who makes the proves and have the issues that send you the debug log of the crash. The developers could try to find the problem with it.